# Combine multiple event with mousemove

Tags: javascript

I have following code to detect the mouse move direction

```js
var direction = "";
var oldx = 0;
var oldy = 0;

mousemovemethod = function(e) {
  if (e.pageX > oldx && e.pageY == oldy) {
    direction = "East";
  } else if (e.pageX == oldx && e.pageY > oldy) {
    direction = "South";
  } else if (e.pageX == oldx && e.pageY < oldy) {
    direction = "North";
  } else if (e.pageX < oldx && e.pageY == oldy) {
    direction = "West";
  }

  document.body.innerHTML = direction;

  oldx = e.pageX;
  oldy = e.pageY;

}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemovemethod);
```

How do I make the above code to work only

1. If left or right click triggered
2. When the mouse moves
3. If user hold the CTRL key and moves the mouse

I know I can detect CTRL click with the following code

```js
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 17) {
    console.log("cntrl key pressed");
  }
});
```

P.s : I need a mousemove event to be called continuously as I am trying to zoom in and zoom out the charts in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two (or more) events (mouse move, keypress (most probably key down and up/release to handle ctrl properly or use the event provided value) and mouse click). Between them create a global variable (i.e. a simple variable that's next to all of the 3 event functions), that's available in all of these event functions. Set this variable to true/false in keypress and mouse click events and check it in the mouse move event.

This code only shows your message if (ctrl is pressed or mouse left/right button is hold down) and the mouse is moved:

```js
var direction = "";
var oldx = 0;
var oldy = 0;
var mouseIsHeld = false;
mouseMoveMethod = function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey || mouseIsHeld) {
        if (e.pageX > oldx && e.pageY == oldy) {
          direction="East";
        }
        else if (e.pageX == oldx && e.pageY > oldy) {
          direction="South";
        }
        else if (e.pageX == oldx && e.pageY < oldy) {
          direction="North";
        }
        else if (e.pageX < oldx && e.pageY == oldy) {
          direction="West";
        }

        document.body.innerHTML = direction;

        oldx = e.pageX;
        oldy = e.pageY;
    }
}

mouseDownMethod = function (e) {
    if (e.button === 0 || e.button === 2) {
        mouseIsHeld = true;
    }
}

mouseUpMethod = function (e) {
    if (e.button === 0 || e.button === 2) {
        mouseIsHeld = false;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveMethod);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownMethod);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpMethod);
// Prevent context menu popup, so we can move our mouse.
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks how do i do it when mouse is being clicked down !

Comment: There it is, from this point you need to be able to customise it as you need to.